# keyboard gets disconnected in the middle of work

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, sp2

I've noticed that my keyboard gets disconnected in the middle of work.  It won't respond to commands.   The indicators for NumLock & CapsLock will go off.  When I uninstall and reinstall the drivers through Device Manager and restart the computer the keyboard will once again come to life.

Is this due to a virus?  Somebody please help me overcome the problem if it is not a virus.

keyboard: TVS Gold Mechanical
OS:  WinXP Pro SP2
AVG Pro Antivirus
AMD Dual Core + ASUS MB

Answer (score 2):

It's **very** unlikely  that this is due to a virus or malware.
A few things to try.

- Verify that you have downloaded the latest drivers.

To check if there is a problem with the keyboard itself.

- Test it on another USB port.
- Test it on another computer.

To check if there is a problem with the computer.

- Test the computer with another keyboard.